# Create output table to summarize data from multiple data-frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a nice table based on information from two databases.

Let's use this as example:

```
row.namess <- c( "s.size", "mean", "sd", "median", "minimum", "maximum")

AVAL1 <- c(250, 7.60, 0.50, 8.30, 5.30, 10.70) ## outcome  

AVAL2 <- c(254, 7.80, 0.68, 7.89, 5.30, 10.60) ## outcome

AGE1 <- c(254, 59.72, 9.08, 59.71, 29.00, 83.00) ## age

AGE2 <- c(254, 55.72, 10.01, 62.71, 31.00, 85.00) ## outcome

 (treatA <- data.frame(AVAL1, AGE1)); rownames(treatA ) <- row.namess

 (treatB <- data.frame(AVAL2, AGE2)); rownames(treatB ) <- row.namess

> treatA
        AVAL1   AGE1
s.size  250.0 254.00
mean      7.6  59.72
sd        0.5   9.08
median    8.3  59.71
minimum   5.3  29.00
maximum  10.7  83.00
> treatB
         AVAL2   AGE2
s.size  254.00 254.00
mean      7.80  55.72
sd        0.68  10.01
median    7.89  62.71
minimum   5.30  31.00
maximum  10.60  85.00
```

I am aiming to find a way to get a nice table (as an image or a table that I can easily copy and use in Word for example) similar to this:

```
                                 Treat A           Treat B          

Number of Subjects                  xxxx              xxxx             
Age (yrs)
  N                                 xxxx              xxxx                  
  Mean (SD)                           xx.x (xx.x)       xx.x (xx.x)       
  Median                              xx.x              xx.x              
  Min ; Max                           xx.x ; xxx.x      xx.x ; xxx.x      

Aval (%)
  N                                 xxxx              xxxx                  
  Mean (SD)                           xx.x (xx.x)       xx.x (xx.x)       
  Median                              xx.x              xx.x              
  Min ; Max                           xx.x ; xxx.x      xx.x ; xxx.x
```

Each column name corresponds to a specific output:
s.size - N
mean - Mean
SD - sd
median - Median 
minimum - Min
maximum - Max

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: knitr and expss packages but I can't get this nice output

Comment: I think there is a package called `broom` which tidies up output from functions like `summary` and `lm`

Comment: But as far as I can see, it can be applied to models outpus and summaries. In this case, I only have dataframes with values (the outputs that I can to plot). I can't figure out a way to have the output above

Comment: One of the reasons you may be getting poor output from knitr and other packages is your use of row names.  In data frames in R the variables are the columns and the rows the observations or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library stargazer is a very good starting point:

`library(stargazer)
 stargazer(mtcars, type = "text", flip = TRUE)`

You can see more here: https://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/#the-default-summary-statistics-table

Best!